# No se puede encontrar el ensamblado

Tags: c#, asp.net

Tengo una aplicación Web que necesita un proyecto llamado TokenService, para que funcione. La aplicación se lanza en dos ventanas diferentes, en una es la aplicación  y en otra el TokenService, el probema está en que en TokenService me arroja el siguiente error. 
Lo curioso es que la aplicación funciona correctamente, excepto cuando retrocedo la navegación hasta llegar el login, ya que aparece el mismo mensaje de error.

> No se puede encontrar el ensamblado 'Ksp.Adac.UI, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

Les dejo también la pila de seguimiento:

> [SerializationException: No se puede encontrar el ensamblado 'Ksp.Adac.UI, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.]
>      System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryAssemblyInfo.GetAssembly() +4199377
>      System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.GetType(BinaryAssemblyInfo assemblyInfo, String name) +14041576
>      System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectMap..ctor(String objectName, String[] memberNames, BinaryTypeEnum[] binaryTypeEnumA, Object[] typeInformationA, Int32[] memberAssemIds, ObjectReader objectReader, Int32 objectId, BinaryAssemblyInfo assemblyInfo, SizedArray assemIdToAssemblyTable) +204
>      System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.__BinaryParser.ReadObjectWithMapTyped(BinaryObjectWithMapTyped record) +284
>      System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.__BinaryParser.Run() +507
>      System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.Deserialize(HeaderHandler handler, __BinaryParser serParser, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage) +169
>      System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream, HeaderHandler handler, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage) +285
>      Microsoft.Web.Redis.BinarySerializer.Deserialize(Byte[] data) in D:\BuildAgent\work\f55792526e6d9089\src\Shared\BinarySerializer.cs:39
>      Microsoft.Web.Redis.StackExchangeClientConnection.GetSessionData(Object rowDataFromRedis) in D:\BuildAgent\work\f55792526e6d9089\src\Shared\StackExchangeClientConnection.cs:236
>      Microsoft.Web.Redis.RedisConnectionWrapper.TryTakeWriteLockAndGetData(DateTime lockTime, Int32 lockTimeout, Object& lockId, ISessionStateItemCollection& data, Int32& sessionTimeout) in D:\BuildAgent\work\f55792526e6d9089\src\RedisSessionStateProvider\RedisConnectionWrapper.cs:196
>      Microsoft.Web.Redis.RedisSessionStateProvider.GetItemFromSessionStore(Boolean isWriteLockRequired, HttpContext context, String id, Boolean& locked, TimeSpan& lockAge, Object& lockId, SessionStateActions& actions) in D:\BuildAgent\work\f55792526e6d9089\src\RedisSessionStateProvider\RedisSessionStateProvider.cs:276
>      Microsoft.Web.Redis.RedisSessionStateProvider.GetItemExclusive(HttpContext context, String id, Boolean& locked, TimeSpan& lockAge, Object& lockId, SessionStateActions& actions) in D:\BuildAgent\work\f55792526e6d9089\src\RedisSessionStateProvider\RedisSessionStateProvider.cs:190
>      System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule.GetSessionStateItem() +176
>      System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule.BeginAcquireState(Object source, EventArgs e, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) +980
>      System.Web.AsyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +636
>      System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +157

Comment: Por favor explica lo siguiente: ¿`TokenService` es una aplicación externa?; revisa en el [GAC "global assembly cache"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/yf1d93sz(v=vs.110).aspx) si tu dll está registrada. [Esta respuesta](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1268359/4092887) re puede orientar mejor sobre GAC.

Comment: No, el token es un proyecto que se ejecuta al mismo tiempo en la misma solción, junto con la aplicación

Comment: Richard, cuando mencionas: `Lo curioso es que la aplicación funciona correctamente, excepto cuando retrocedo la navegación hasta llegar el login` = ¿qué código usas para la navegación?, me pregunto porque para mí _personalmente_ no es muy claro cómo eso afecta tu proyecto.

Comment: Es una aplicación web, cuando el usuario presiona el botón de volver del navegador, hasta llegar al login, este muestra esa pantalla